# Getting error while installing ubuntu landscape

Tags: landscape

I have been trying to install ubuntu landscape server using this link https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/QuickStart and i am getting error in steps 6.IN this above link canonical mention /etc/landscape/server.conf file which is not in my system.

please help me for this

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the exact error as far as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have landscape-server installed? Note it's proprietary software and not available in the ubuntu archive.  It has to be purchased.